# Error when trying to access data of relation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I've been using Laravel 4 for a few days now and I stumbled across something I can't seem to fix.

Using Eloquent, I've set up 2 models, where `Appointment` has a `belongsTo` relationship to `Room`.
After retrieving it like so (using eager loading):

```
$appointments = Appointment::with('room')->get();
```

I'm printing it in my view: http://paste.laravel.com/fnL

I loop through it and retrieve a value of Appointment:

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $appointment->begins_at }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/admin/appointments/delete/{{ $appointment->id }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">Verwijderen</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This works fine, but when I add the following line:

```
<td>{{ $appointment->room->name }}</td>
```

It throws the following error:

```
ErrorException: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I'm probably just overlooking something, but I've been looking at it for quite some time and I just don't see it...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second appointment in the collection does not have a room, thus, `$appointment->room` is `null`, so You are essentially doing `null->name`

[image]

Solution is to check if the room is set.

```
@if($appointment->room)
    {{ $appointment->room->name }}
@endif
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I've definitely been working too long on this application... Thanks a lot!